Bijection to a Non-Empty Set from Its Quotient Set Achieved from a Relation Induced by a Function on it
Let us suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a function and $R$ is the relation on $X$ induced by $f$. Then, $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.
Proof:  As $R \subseteq X \times X$ is induced by $f:X \rightarrow Y$, therefore $x_1Rx_2 \iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$
Reflexivity: Let, $x \in X$. Clearly $f(x)=f(x)$. Thus, $(x,x) \in R$. As $x \in X$ is arbitary, therefore $\forall x \in X,(x,x) \in \Bbb{R}$. Hence, $R$ is reflexive.
Symmetry: Let, $x,y \in X$ such that $xRy$. Therefore $f(x)=f(y)$, which can also be written as $f(y)=f(x) \implies yRx$. As $x,y \in X$ are arbitrary, therefore $\forall x,y \in X, xRy \implies yRx$. Hence, $R$ is symmetric.
Transitivity: Let, $x,y,z \in X$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$. Now, $xRy \implies f(x)=f(y)$ and $yRz \implies f(y)=f(z)$. Therefore, $f(x)=f(z) \implies xRz$. As $x,y,z \in X$ are arbitrary, therefore $\forall x,y,z \in X, xRy$ and $yRz \implies xRz$. Hence, R is transitive.
Thus, we can conclude that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.
Problem: Let us consider the fucntion $\phi : \frac{X}{R} \rightarrow Y$ defined by $\phi ([x])=f(x)$. Then show that $\phi$ is bijective.
Solution: First let us verify that $\phi$ is well-defined. Let, $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $[x_1]=[x_2]$.
$\therefore x_1Rx_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ [By definition of R] $\implies$ $\phi ([x_1])=\phi([x_2])$ [By definition of $\phi$]
$\therefore \phi$ is well-defined.
Injectivity :
Let, $[x_1],[x_2] \in \frac{X}{R}$ such that $\phi([x_1])=\phi([x_2])$.
$\therefore f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ [By definition of $\phi$]
$\implies x_1Rx_2$ [By definition of R]
$\implies x_1 \in [x_2]$ [By definition of $[x_2]$]
$\implies [x_1]=[x_2]$ [By Lemma 4.4.1, Page 87]
Thus, it can be concluded that $\phi$ is injective.
Surjectivity: Let $y \in Y$ be arbitarily chosen. To prove that $\phi$ is surjective, some $[x] \in \frac{X}{R}$ must be found such that $y=\phi ([x])=f(x)$. The problem is that it is not given that $f$ is onto. Then, how is it possible to prove that $\phi$ is onto? And if $\phi$ is not onto, how should I prove that? I have not achieved any counter-example yet.
References from the Textbook :
Equivalence Relation (Definition 4.3.1, Page 84),
Relation Induced by a Function (Definition 4.3.12, Page 86),
Quotient Set (Definition 4.4.9, Page 91)

Yes, $f$ must be onto in order for the result to follow. Otherwise consider the example in which $|X|=1$ is a singleton and $|Y|>1$; there is no bijection between $X$ and $Y$ (note that any quotient of a singleton is again a singleton).

@amrsa Understandable. Maybe I should change the codomain of $\phi$ to $f(X)$ i.e. range of $f$. That may work I suppose. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You are absolutely right! If $f:X\to Y$ is any function, then $f':X\to f(X)$ given by $f'(x)=f(x)$ is onto.
